# MySQL Workbench: How do you move query results to a separate window?

Tags: mysql-workbench

Is there a way to move query results to a separate window? I would like to move my results from queries to another monitor, and have them always appear there once ran. Does `MySQL Workbench` offer this type of customization? I am on `version 8.0.17`.

[image: example-of-results]